# Scroller in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, scroller

I want to develop class like gallery widget on iPhone,but on android. And i use linearlayout inherited class with scroller inside(for fling).Where i can see example scroller fling in layout?Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

you can get an example [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example) . it will be very helpfull for you

Comment: ScrollView don't have possibility going beyond the content and automatic return(dont know name of this effect)

Comment: This will scroll untill widgets added to the layout